# Apache Camel and Google PuSub integration

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to Java/Camel/GCP and I'm attempting to create an Apache Camel project that integrates with Google PubSub. Basically, I have a topic and a payload and I need to be able to publish a message, queue messages, subscribe or handle any errors.
Are there any good examples out there that do this or how do I approach this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started with the Apache camel integration with Cloud Pub/Sub, I would recommend going about implementing the unit test of the same which is mentioned in their official GitHub [thread](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/8bb5c67e9421a13d87474c67048ca278d621e074/components/camel-google/camel-google-pubsub). To test it out in the local you can make use of the [PubSub Emulator](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/8bb5c67e9421a13d87474c67048ca278d621e074/components/camel-google/camel-google-pubsub/ReadMe.md).
All the examples for testing are available [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/8bb5c67e9421a13d87474c67048ca278d621e074/components/camel-google/camel-google-pubsub/src/test).

Comment: Thank you! This has been helpful